# Problem in Using FILTER and DROPDOWN in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to filter a list in Google Sheets.
I defined a drop_down filled with the values of a table's column.
And I wrote a simple FILTER function to filter the list based on the value of the dropdown.

When the dropdown has a value, everything works fine.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2f3.png)

But when the user doesn't select a value for the dropdown, I want the list appears with NO FILTER. I want to see all rows of the list. But FILTER assumes it should display the rows with that value equal to "", so it shows no row at all.[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RsCQ.png)

I can use IF, but since in my original file, I have multiple dropdowns, it won't be functional.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give us additional information in order to be able to help, since stating some IFs clauses would solve it.

But you may try changing the part of your filter where you state the equality and change it with REGEXMATCH. For example:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,Sheet1!B:B=B2)
```

To:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B:B,B2))
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I could easily create what I need with a simple IF if I had just one dropdown. But assume I have 6 dropdowns. And checking all the combinations in which the dropdown is empty, so I don't consider it in FILTER formula, ends up checking 64 different conditions.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested?? It should possibly work just changing the equals in the filter with REGEXMATCH